# Compare two column values and get distinct values from first column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compare column1 and column2 and get the unique values from column1 (ignoring `NaN`). So in this case, I should get `test1`, `test4`.

Also, can we create and store the result in another column?

```
    Column1 column2    
0   test1   test2   
1   test2   test3   
2   test3   hello  
3   test4   world   
4     NaN     how  
5     NaN     are   
6     NaN     you
```

Comment: sorry for the bad edit. I tried it using code block , but still shows it bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these values by doing

```
set(df.column1)-set(df.column2)-set([None])
```

Also, if you want to store the result in another column, you can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd    
df=pd.DataFrame({'column1':['t1','t2','t3',None],'column2':['t1','a',None,None]})
unique_vals=list(set(df.column1)-set(df.column2)-set([None]))
df['new_col']=unique_vals+['None']*(len(df)-len(unique_vals))
df
```

and the result is:

```
  column1   column2 new_col
0   t1       t1      t2
1   t2       a       t3
2   t3      None    None
3   None    None    None
```

Comment: It works. Thank you . I have accepted this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without referencing the column names
**explanation**

- I `stack` because it is a convenient way to drop nan's and not force a rectangular shape.
- grouping by `level=1` is the same as by columns prior to stacking.
- applying `set` will allow me to use subtraction or `diff` which is interpreted as `set.difference` which is what we want.
- `[::-1]` just reverses the order so I get the correct difference.

---

```
np.diff(df.stack().groupby(level=1).apply(set).values[::-1])

array([{'test4', 'test1'}], dtype=object)
```